# Altering module behavior in OCaml

Tags: java, ocaml

I have a set of ints whose input I'd like to restrict. I would like it to behave something like the following:

```
# RestrictedIntSet.add 15 (RestrictedIntSet.make 0 10)
Exception: 15 out of acceptable range [0 .. 10]
```

How can I implement this? In Java, it could look something like:

```
Set<Integer> restrictedSet = new HashSet<Integer>() {
    public boolean add(Integer i) {
        if (i < lowerBound || i > upperBound) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("out of bounds");
        }
        return super.add(i);
    }
```

Or, to be less abusing of inheritance:

```
public class RestrictedSet {

   private int lowerBound;
   private int upperBound;
   private Set elems = Sets.newHashSet();

   public RestrictedSet(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
      this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
      this.upperBound = upperBound;
   }

   public boolean add(Integer i) {
      if (i < lowerBound || i > upperBound) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("out of bounds");
      }
      return elems.add(i);   
   }

   /* fill in other forwarded Set calls as needed */
}
```

What is the equivalent, idiomatic way to do this in OCaml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it depends, which `set` library are you using?

Using the [Set](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.html) module of the standard library, you could do the following:

```
module type RestrictedOrderedType = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val lower_bound : t
  val upper_bound : t
end

module RestrictedSet (Elem : RestrictedOrderedType) = struct
  include Set.Make(Elem)

  exception Not_in_range of Elem.t

  let check e =
    if Elem.compare e Elem.lower_bound < 0
     || Elem.compare e Elem.upper_bound > 0
    then raise (Not_in_range e)
    else e

  (* redefine a new 'add' in term of the one in Set.Make(Elem) *)
  let add e s = add (check e) s

  let singleton e = singleton (check e)
end


(* test *)
module MySet = RestrictedSet(struct
  type t = int
  let compare = compare
  let lower_bound = 0
  let upper_bound = 10
end)

let test1 = MySet.singleton 3

let test2 = MySet.add (-3) test1
(* Exception: Not_in_range (-3) *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @gasches's answer.

As a short complement: OCaml's Set module is designed to be instantiated by an OrderedType module, which means you cannot directly use OCaml's native `int`s directly.

One thus needs to use a module that complies with the requested signature. gasche's definition of a RestrictedOrderedType signature does this *and* elegantly includes the lower and upper bound fields. A rougher approach would be to use OCaml's Int32 or Int64 modules, which conform to the requested OrderedType signature, and hard-code the bounds in the `MySet` module.

Below is a slight reformulation of gasche's example to illustrate this point.

```
  module MySet = struct
    include Set.Make(Int32)

    exception Not_in_range of Int32.t  

    let lower_bound = Int32.of_int 5

    let upper_bound = Int32.of_int 10

    let add elt set = 
      if (elt < lower_bound)||(elt > upper_bound)
      then raise (Not_in_range elt)
      else add elt set

  end;;
```